# Probability Distribution Calculation of Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**Question**

Let Y be a random variable with probability distribution

$$
P(Y=y) = ks^{y-1}
$$

For $y = 1,2,3...$ and $0<s<1$

Determine the value of $k$ that determine if this is a valid probability distribution.

**My attempt**

I understand that sum of all probabilities for this function should be equal to 1.

$$\mathrm{P}(Y = y_{n}) = \sum_{i=1}^n{\mathrm{P}(Y=y) = 1}$$

Given the conditions, I have substituted in $y = 1,2,3$ to determine an equation for determine the value of $k$.

\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{Pr}(Y = 1) &= ks^{(1)-1} = k \\
    \mathrm{Pr}(Y = 2) &= ks^{(2)-1} = ks \\
    \mathrm{Pr}(Y = 3) &= ks^{(3)-1} = ks^2
\end{align*}

This results in the following.
$$
k + ks + ks^2 = 1
$$

Computing for the interval $0<s<1$ by substituting in $s = 0$ and $s= 1$, I have computed the values of $k = \frac{1}{3}$ and $k = 1$. Would I be correct in doing so?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they say "for $y = 1,2,3...$, note the dots: "$...$"

That means $y$ can take on *any* positive integer value: the sum doesn't stop at the third term. So you want

$$1 = \sum_{y=1}^\infty P(Y=y),$$

not

$$1 = \sum_{y=1}^3 P(Y=y).$$

[Also: it's not enough to calculate $k$ for a couple of different values of $s$, in the end, your $k$ should be a function of $s$.]

So what you get is: $1 = k + ks + ks^2 + ... + ks^{n-1} + ...$, and you'll need to remember stuff you learned long ago about Geometric series, specifically, that

$k + ks + ks^2 + ... + ks^{n-1} + ... = \frac{k}{1-s}$.

So, $\frac k{1-s}=1$, and $k=1-s$.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense! Thank you